# stringWithUTF8String fails, but only sometimes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following bit of code:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:0 error:&fileError];
NSString *recipe = @"";
if (fileError == nil) {
     recipe = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
     NSLog(@"Converted Recipe as: %@",recipe);
     NSLog(@"Original Data was: %@",data);  
} else {
     NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", [fileError localizedDescription]);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the stringWithUTF8String returns null and sometimes it correctly returns the contents of the file... The SAME file.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  Here's a snippet from the log when it does not....  Which means to me that the file read is working, but for some reason the conversion has failed this time.  If I do it again  (this is called as the result of a tableView  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  So I can just click on a different row and then come back to this one.

```
2010-08-01 16:14:29.031 RecipeBrowse[52056:207] Converted Recipe as: (null)
2010-08-01 16:14:29.037 RecipeBrowse[52056:207] Original Data was: <426c6163 6b656e65 64204361 626f2046 69736820 5461636f 730a0a49 4e475245 4449454e 54533a0a 0a2d200a 0a0a4d45 54484f44 3a0a0a42 4c41434b 454e4544 20434142 4f204649 53482054 41434f53
```

Any ideas how to make this more reliable??

Comment: Go back and read the docs on error handling. NEVER test if the error is non-nil; ALWAYS test the return value (data in this case) instead.

Answer (score 33):

`+stringWithUTF8String:` will assume that its input is a NUL-terminated string, but NSData doesn't put any particular terminator there.  Instead, create your string using `-initWithBytes:length:encoding:`, since you know the length of the data.

Comment: Or `initWithData:encoding:`.

Comment: 3 years later and your answer solved my problem!
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Because of this issue my presentation failed. So i learned something today. Next time, when i am about to use the function, RTFM carefully. I have totally missed NULL from _"A NULL-terminated C array of bytes in UTF8 encoding."_

Comment: You sire, are a genius

Comment: Hello, here is 2021, there has been a pandemic and your answer is still super useful.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, initWithData:data works for me

```
- (NSString *)base64String {
    NSData * data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```